# How to deploy client-side service WSDLs

Tags: wsdl, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have code using the SysOperationFrameworkService, and after a model-deploy or some other set of circumstances, many users get `Function SysOperationDataContractInfo::newParameterInfo has been incorrectly called.`.

It's unable to be resolved with full-compile, sync, full CIL, deleting XPPIL files, deleting AUC/KTI, usage data, security (they're admin), refreshing caches (server &client), etc. and I have a ticket open with Microsoft and they're struggling.

I've narrowed the issue down to when the service group `AxClient` located in the AOT at `\Service Groups\AxClient` WSDL files get deployed to `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local`.  Either those files existing there, or something happening when those files get deployed is needed.

Any idea how/what causes these files (AxClient.wsdl, etc) to be created?  With a user who happens to be "working", I can close the client, delete all the files, open the client, and no files will exist...then I perform a SysOp process and those files get created during that process.  With the non-working user, with same security on the same machine does it, the files don't get created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the

> "Function SysOperationDataContractInfo::newParameterInfo has been incorrectly called" has been throwed because of a possible bug in the kernel when calling the "dictMethod = new DictMethod(UtilElementType::ClassInstanceMethod, dictClass.id(), methodName);" in the  SysOperationServiceController.getServiceOperation() method. In my case the new DictMethod was sometimes unable to get the method parameter from a superclass, causing the _parentMethodParameterName check fail in the SysOperationDataContractInfo.newParameterInfo.

So, I solved the issue just by doing an `override of the super method` where the parameter could not be retrieved and then just calling `super(_parameter)`, then everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried axclicfg.exe -> connections -> refresh

Comment: Yes many times.  I actually think it's a bug with the way the SysOperationFramework handles complex levels of abstraction.  If I give the erroring user sys-admin and then go to Tools>Options>Developer, turn breakpoint on, then it works.  But if I set that feature from another user via SystemAdmin>Users>Options, it does not work, even if they're sys admin.  Some bizzare issue. I think it's kernel bug combined with usage data.